# Android - Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, exception

when I try to run my app i get this error on LogCat:

```
08-23 17:32:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 17:32:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapp/com.library.core.presentation.SessionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 17:32:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
08-23 17:32:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
```

the problem appears when i touch on a list item, corresponding to this Intent:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent sessionIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SessionActivity.class);                
            //sessionIntent.putExtras(bundle);                      
            startActivity(sessionIntent);

        }
```

SessionActivity is a class contained in a library project that i have to use for this app.
My Manifest file is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.rdp.rdp_prova.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity android:name="com.library.core.presentation.SessionActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

what's wrong?

Comment: had You added this library to build path?

Comment: use activity context `Intent sessionIntent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, SessionActivity.class)` and post the full stacktrace

Comment: @Raghunandan i get the error the same!

Comment: @Opiatefuchs if i open Properties->Android in the section Library it appears..